# Convert 220V AC to give out TWO 12V DC 3 amps

Tags: transformer, mains, rectifier, 12v, dual

I need an output of two 12 v dc 3amps , how can do it with a single transformer ?

Well i am sorry for i framed the question badly!

I have an appliance that need needs 12v 2amp for one component (heater) and 12v 2amp (motor) how do i get that ?

Comment: This question is unclear and misses a lot of important information out. Does this design require an off the shelf transformer or is custom design allowed?  What regulation is required for the two outputs?  Are the two outputs required to be isolated from each other and if yes what level of isolation peak voltage is required?

Answer (score 2):

> I need an output of two 12 v dc 3amps

In the absence of a proper specification this circuit has two outputs of 12 V. Ability to supply 3 A each will depend on your transformer and diode selection.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNvAPK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you would like to improve the question then we could improve the answer.